# Как избежать бана в телеграм

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

Проблема такая: пишу бота на telethon. Так как телега в рф заблокирована, бот работает через прокси, а сам я сижу без прокси (почему-то приложение и так работает, а к апи обратиться не получается, блокировка). В момент запуска бота нужно подтвердить, что это ты, и вписать код в терминал. И тут сразу прилетает бан аккаунта. Один раз забанили после нескольких запусков бота, потом я решил зарегать отдельный акк и тогда при первом запуске забанили сразу. 
Как этого избежать? Бан прилетает из-за того что вход из разных стран одновременно? Поможет ли установка впн и вход с одного адреса или у телеграма какие-то другие причины?

Comment: А зачем бот работает через прокси когда можно просто не юзать российских хостеров?

Comment: можно поподробнее?

Comment: Зачем сразу после регистрации аккаунт сразу добавлять в бота? Как минимум только что зарегистрированному аккаунту нужно отлега в виде 24 часов.